# Query IIS FastCGI settings from PHP

Tags: php, iis

I am trying to programmatically query the FastCGI settings configured in IIS through PHP's COM API using WMI.

Using WMI CIM Studio I can see there is a FastCgiSection class which has a FastCgi member array that contains exactly the settings I want (specifically ActivityTimeout and RequestTimeout): [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb422421(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb422421%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

However, any attempt at querying this so far has not succeeded. The examples of querying Win32_Processor and so on that you can find online work fine, but translating that into a query of the FastCgiSection isn't working out.

So far I have this, which isn't outputting anything:

```
$wmi = new \COM('winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}//./root/WebAdministration');
$arrData = $wmi->ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM FastCgiSection");
foreach ($arrData as $obj) {
   echo "has result";
}
```

How do I access this API through WMI in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query returns [`FastCgiSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb422421.aspx) objects, while the FastCGI application settings are stored in [`FastCgiApplicationElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb422403.aspx) class.

Your code doesn't access `FastCgi` member, only the objects returned by the WMI query. You need another loop over the `FastCgi` property in order to get what you want:

```
$wmi=new COM('winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}//./root/WebAdministration');
foreach($wmi->ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM FastCgiSection') as $section) {
  foreach($section->FastCgi as $application) {
    echo $application->ActivityTimeout, PHP_EOL;
    echo $application->RequestTimeout, PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

Note that, in order for this code to work, you'll need to:

- enable [COM/.NET extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) in "php.ini" file (as stated by Jonathon Hibbard).
- [install IIS 7's WMI Provider](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/scripting/managing-sites-with-the-iis-wmi-provider#01).

Comment: I've checked that everything is enabled, but that ExecQuery statement doesn't produce any results for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes :) The query returns one result on my machine, corresponding to my PHP/FastCGI application defined in IIS (v7.5), in "FastCGI Settings" section. Using a standard setup as in: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/fastcgi

Comment: I'm going to assign you the bounty for the example code to point me in the right direction. I'll keep digging to find out why it's not working for me.

Comment: Thanks :) Maybe the user running the WMI query... It works on my machine in command line, using my administrator account. In a Web page, using IIS account (IUSR), the query returns nothing (I doubt that IUSR account have access to IIS metabase).

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you haven't already seen it, here is a pretty good link going into a lot of detail about doing very close to the same thing you're trying: http://www.sitepoint.com/php-wmi-dig-deep-windows-php/

One thing that I'd say to do ( if you haven't already ) is to check and verify the following is enabled in your php.ini: `extension=php_com_dotnet.dll`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had previously seen that article, and used its approach to query other WMI properties, but it didn't help me to deal with the specific cast of the FastCgiSection collection.